# Localisation of Javascript Calendar

Tags: javascript, localization, calendar

Does the calendar get the month names from the users computer, or is this predefined in the control itself?

I.e. for the same piece of code, would it say "June" when viewing it on an English PC and the German equivalent when viewing it on a German PC?

I am not too familiar with this I must admit.  I guess CalendarPopup(); is used?

Comment: What calendar are you talking about?

Comment: Wouldn't that be CalendarPopup(); ?

I don't mind what calendar is used, but I need a javascript calendar so that the user can view a month, change month and select a date.  Ideally the localisation would be handled by the control itself, using the users local settings...

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not have a native method that derives the localised names for days & months. The localised data functions native to JavaScript only return dates in the numerical formats as defined by the user's system locale conventions.

Those methods are [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), & [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

All the other methods that do return human readable names for months, do so in American English.

JavaScript 1.6 implements a new method "[toLocaleFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat)" that is non-standard but would be able to provide you with the names of days & months.

Most JavaScript Date Picker widgets employs some collection of objects containing the localised names.